# Is my description of the language accepted by this DFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa, automata-theory

Image of DFA: https://ibb.co/LCW99q9

From my understanding, any string is accepted as long as it contains the substring “abc”; anything before is okay, and everything after is okay, including “λ”.
My problem is that I’m not sure how to write the notation, so is this correct? 
L = {wabcv: v,w ∈ {a,b,c}*}

Comment: Your answer is correct and your notation is proper. There's nothing to add to your answer except possibly a proof of correctness. To produce a proof of your answer you could argue first that the only way to accept is to see the substring abc, at which point acceptance is guaranteed; then, argue that for each of the non-accepting states, seeing the substring abc leads to guaranteed acceptance.

Comment: Oh your proof is better, thank you!

Comment: @nancy It seems as if your question have been answered. If so, please confirm one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. That is:
`L = {wabcv: v,w ∈ {a,b,c}*}`